# How can I get a "whole treatment effect" for a 3 level categorical variable in a GLMM (glmmPQL in R)

Tags: r, categorical-data, random-effects-model, glmm

I work with habitat use data (summarized binomial data: visited / did not visit) which I fitted with a mixed model of the binomial family with a random factor accounting for repeated sampling of the same individual. I simply want basic descriptions of the data - effects of sex and year on the proportion of time spent in each habitat.

The code is as follow (for a basic model without interaction):

```
Colony.glmmSexYear <- glmmPQL(cbind(ColoYes.allnoF24, ColoNo.allnoF24) ~ 
                              year.coded + sex, random= ~1| BirdID, 
                              family=binomial(), data=mydata)
summary(Colony.glmmSexYear)
```

Here is the fixed effects section of my output:

```
Fixed effects: cbind(ColoYes.allnoF24, ColoNo.allnoF24) ~ year.coded + sex

                     Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)      1.4442270 0.1824173 74  7.917161  0.0000
year.codedY2011 -0.1733713 0.1864744 74 -0.929732  0.3555
year.codedY2012 -0.3004284 0.2027411 74 -1.481833  0.1426
sexM             0.4403108 0.1507471 74  2.920857  0.0046
```

You were supposed to see that 2011-2012 is also not significant (not shown).

In traditional linear models I would report the p value for the whole treatment "year" from an ANOVA associated with a F test (i.e, just one p value), not the individual p values of the various year comparisons (3 p-values). But my understanding is that producing an ANOVA from `glmmPQL` is not possible (?). Reporting those three individual p values of my multiple year comparisons really seems clumsy and out of place...

What is the proper way to do this? Should I not be using `glmmPQL`?

Specification: I cut into the background description of the study for simplicity, but this is not a resource selection study - please do not suggest using resource selection models.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Marie! You may test the coefficients of `year.codedY2011` and `year.codedY2012` jointly by either a likelihood ratio test or Wald test.